# How to get Height data given during registration from Googlefit REST Apis

Tags: rest, height, google-fit

I am new to google fit rest APIs and I have been trying to calculate BMI of a user for my project.

So, when the user authorizes to my application at that time I get data for the last 30 days (historical data for some calculation). From then on I extract data periodically this way I always get the latest weight data.
But the issue comes in the scenario when the user has been using google fit way before authentication because I wouldn't know the exact date I should pass as parameter to extract height data.

The aggregate data type accepts the date range of only 90 days, else it returns the error as *aggregate duration too large* . But the user's height data could be as old as 2/3 years.
I also looked at the option of custom data types, but there again I don't know the exact date range to make an API call.

Is there any way that I can either get the user's joining date (the date he/she registered to  Google fit) because a user has to provide height during registration or if I could somehow get data under *About you* (Gender, DoB, Weight, Height) in **Profile tab**
Or If I could get the calculated BMI data point directly from API.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "else it returns the error as aggregate duration too large" Don't use the Aggregate method. Use https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get.

Comment: In any case, I can only give 90 days as date range, which is not a feasible solution to what I'm trying to achieve